# Zabbix 3.0 with PagerDuty not working

Tags: zabbix

I have configured an Ubuntu 14.04 server on Digital Ocean with Zabbix 3.0 server. I'm now trying to integrate the PagerDuty service (www.pagerduty.com) on Zabbix. I installed the PagerDuty zabbix agent and can trigger an incident with that agent form the CLI on Ubuntu. However when there is a trigger in Zabbix the PagerDuty agent is not sending the incidents to PagerDuty. However I can see that Zabbix sent the PagerDuty alert, but apparently there is something broken.

Where do I start to debug this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you followed the PagerDuty instructions for Zabbix 2.x

1. Make sure `pd-zabbix` is located where Zabbix can find it, I think Zabbix 2 was looking for it at `/etc/zabbix/alerts.d` while Zabbix 3 seems to be looking in `/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts`
2. Then make sure zabbix is calling `pd-zabbix` properly, to debug that I created a script that just logs command line arguments and stdin to a file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys

with open('/tmp/pd-zabbix.log', 'a+') as f:
    print("args:", sys.argv, file=f)
    print(sys.stdin.read(), file=f)
    print("-----", file=f)
```

And I've noticed that Zabbix 3.x doesn't pass any arguments. In Zabbix 3.x you can define exactly what it passed and the order. Go to *Administration* -> *Media types* -> click on the PagerDuty media you probably defined (the place where you selected type script and wrote `pd-zabbix`) and add the following argument (as 3 separate parameters)

- `{ALERT.SENDTO}`
- `{ALERT.SUBJECT}`
- `{ALERT.MESSAGE}`

[Zabbix custom alert scripts](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Confirmed that this was also the issue for me. I caught the different location for alertscripts and noticed the addition of a parameters field but didn't know what they were.

Thanks a ton for posting this!! I've linked the Zabbix support team to your answer here and have asked them to add this to their docs.

Comment: You should check out ngDesk instead as its totally free and has more features then pager duty. You can check it out here https://www.ngdesk.com